# Window 2008 SP1. Administrative tool not functional

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I am configuring a Window 2008 32bit SP1 server and could not access its ServerManager window, in the Administrative tool, the item ServerManager will just open Computer Management window instead.

[image: enter link description here]

Aside from that, I also access Window features as well, it will simply pop up an error with the path as in screenshot.

[image: enter link description here]

The server is just freshly installed so most things should be default. What is the cause and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing from different media. This type of problem should not be occurring this early in the setup process. I would not trust this machine to be stable, so don't fix the problem, blow it away with a a new install from new media.